Keyboard is pushing the Status Bar and CenterAlignedTopAppBar on top in Compose Multiplatform
I have a Compose Multiplatform app here that shows a Signup screen in my Column content inside a Scaffold. As you can see on the gif. link below, When the cursor is further down on the fields, the status bar and topup bar will no longer show.
I wanted for the status bar and the top bar to be pinned on the top always. I have tried adding a WindowInsets.ime but it's just giving a lot of padding above the keyboard but the status bar and the top bar still shows hidden.
Here's my shared code:
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
            title = {
                // Some title here
            },
            navigationIcon = {
                // Some icon here
            }
        )
    }
) {
    Column {
        // My content here
    }
}

Here's my ContentView.swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ComposeView()
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all) // Add this line to let Compose handle keyboard
    }
}

https://jumpshare.com/s/fY4t4zspxsURCwDbwVO8
Previously on my android code, there's an adjustResize that you can put on your AndroidManifest.xml, is there a similar way to compose multiplatform?
